# How to show NULL results from query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, null

i'm trying to create a procedure with filters for search.

If the parameter is "NULL" the value of parameter will be column value;

Here my problem: When my parameter and column value is NULL.

I have no results because of this.

I know that query: "COLUMN_NAME IS NULL" return the result even if the value is NULL, but i don't know how to implement this.

I trying to do this with "CASE" but without success.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SEARCH_QUERYS
        @ID   int,
        @LIVE bit,
        @DATA datetime
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM TB_SEARCH
        WHERE 
        ID = ISNULL(@ID,ID) AND
        LIVE = ISNULL(@LIVE,LIVE) AND
        DATA = ISNULL(@DATA,DATA)
END
```

Comment: It is generally not a good practice (INMO) to allow nulls in a column named ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SEARCH_QUERYS -- always use schema prefix!
        @ID   int,
        @LIVE bit,
        @DATA datetime
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT ID, LIVE, DATA --, ... don't use SELECT *!
        FROM dbo.TB_SEARCH -- always use schema prefix!
        WHERE 
        (ID = @ID OR @ID IS NULL)
        AND (LIVE = @LIVE OR @LIVE IS NULL)
        AND (DATA = @DATA OR @DATA IS NULL); -- always use semi-colons!
END
GO
```

In some cases though you are better off building the query dynamically.

Refs:

- [Not using SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- [Using schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [Using statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)

Comment: Aaron, this query is exactly what i tried before! Don't work.
Note: Column "DATA" default value is NULL.

also: What is difference between my query and yours?

Comment: @Laerte does "Don't work" mean you tried it before and it didn't work, but now it does, or that this doesn't work now?

Comment: I tried right now and still don't work.

Comment: Also: What is difference between my query and yours?

Comment: @Laerte your query says `ISNULL(@param, column) = column`. This comparison does not work if the column is `NULL` because `NULL = NULL` is unknown, not true. In a `WHERE` clause this means reject the row. My query says "if the parameter is NULL, return the row; if the parameter IS NOT NULL, return the row only if the column matches." Did you try this logic on all three of your columns/parameters, or just the `ID` column? Can you show some sample data that demonstrates how this does not work?

Comment: @Laerte [here's a sample, please let me know what about this doesn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36686/3).

Comment: Now it's working, thanks you very much for your patience and for explain to me.

I found this snippet that you posted in a forum, now I understand how it worked, thanks!